# Dart switch with String cases, performance

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, optimization

I was wondering how switch which uses strings as a constants in case block is implemented? When I do debug, and do Step by step execution, I see that execution goes from one case to another linear. So it looks like syntax sugar which in reality is chain of if/else. I would rather expect some compiler optimisation here. My question then is if `Map<String, _lambda>` will be faster then switch/case for strings? I would rather not do any naive time measurements since this can lead to wrong conclusions.

Comment: You should do what makes your code most readable and only do performance optimizations like this if you can measure a performance problem related to your code. This question is very much context dependent so not easy to answer. E.g. how many cases are there? How many times are you calling this method?... and so on.

Comment: This is method which will be delivered as provider of data for parsing process. It will be used heavily, and count of switch cases is hard to determine. Since for various parsers it will be different. Question is not context dependent, it's states: Is switch/case for string keys is unwinded into chain of if-else?

Comment: Yes, switch statements in Dart is unwinded into chain of if-else calls. But, the Dart compiler can then do some optimizations based around the fact we are using Strings and makes a lot of if statements around that. So I have seen the compiler do clever things when it optimizes this code which also makes it hard to compare the behavior of running in debugging with how the code runs in release mode and compiled.

Comment: Ok, that was the answer which I was unable to find. So I can expect optimisations for such cases, and there is no need to search alternative. Because speed of hashmap and linear search is quite different.

Comment: In short, you are trying to outsmart the compiler. Don't try doing that unless you can measure a problem. And if you can measure a problem where the compiler could be smarter, make an issue on the Dart SDK tracker so we can get the compiler to be improved in future versions. :)

Comment: "Because speed of hashmap and linear search is quite different." You are assuming that Dart compiles multiple if-statements on Strings into a linear search. That is not necessary an assumption you can make. E.g. it could do some lookup tables in theory.

Comment: That's why I ask about it, because it was quite "shocking" for me. Whole idea of using switch case is to have it more readable and faster then chain of ifs. But if switch was only different syntax for ifs then I can use different approaches. And again I didn't assume anything, just ask because I was unable to find such info for Dart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239705/discussion-between-julemand101-and-the-tosters).